# equation numbering looks wrong

Tags: numbering, hebrew

I am using a template for my thesis, which must involve some Hebrew text as well. The problem is that the parentheses on the equation numbering looks like )1.3) (see the picture posted).  [image]

I guess this happens because of some package having to do with Hebrew, but the template is too complicated to my modest knowledge in Latex. Any way to fix only this without changing other things in the template?

I tried to produce an MWE. The main file code is something like

```
\documentclass[]{misc/iitthesis}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\include{main/mainchap1}
\end{document}
```

and the iithesis file looks like

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\AtEndPreamble{
 \setotherlanguage[]{hebrew}
}
```

and the mainchap1.tex file looks like

```
\chapter{A main chapter}

\begin{align}
e &= mc^2
\end{align}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142604/discussion-on-question-by-yonatan-equation-numbering-looks-wrong); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the source of the problem comes from using outdated TeXLive version (see the comments), with TeXLive 2022 the bug is gone.